# "rune literal not terminated" error when attempting to run gofmt -r with exec.Command

Tags: shell, go, gofmt

In the following directory structure,

```
.
├── foo.go
├── go.mod
└── main.go
```

I have a `foo.go` with a simple type definition:

```golang
package main

type Foo struct {
    Baz string
}
```

If I run `gofmt -r` from the command line to replace a variable name, it works:

```
> gofmt -r 'Foo -> Bar' foo.go
package main

type Bar struct {
    Baz string
}
```

However, if I try to do this from `main.go` with the program

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os/exec"
)

func main() {
    combinedOutput, err := exec.Command("gofmt", "-r", "'Foo -> Bar'", "foo.go").CombinedOutput()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("gofmt foo.go: %v. Combined output: %s", err, combinedOutput)
    }
    fmt.Println(string(combinedOutput))
}
```

I get an error:

```
> go run main.go
2023/01/14 23:42:07 gofmt foo.go: exit status 2. Combined output: parsing pattern 'Foo  at 1:1: rune literal not terminated
exit status 1
```

Any idea what is causing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to quote arguments to `exec.Command`; quoting is a feature of your shell, and doesn't apply when you make system calls. It's also not necessary, because quoting is done to delineate arguments in the shell, but in `exec.Command`, the arguments are separated as arguments to the function call.

Concretely:

```
exec.Command("gofmt", "-r", "'Foo -> Bar'", "foo.go")
```

should be

```
exec.Command("gofmt", "-r", "Foo -> Bar", "foo.go")
```